# Access drive by label under rsync/cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, rsync

I have downloaded rsync for Windows.

It uses cygwin.

My rsync command is this:

```
rsync.exe -W -a -v --delete --exclude=cache2 --exclude=Cache "/cygdrive/C/Users/user1/" "/cygdrive/F/backup/"
```

As you can see I have specified the target drive like this:

```
/cygdrive/F
```

Is there a way to specify target drive by label instead of drive letter?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Cygwin mounts Windows drives and partitions with drive letter not
with drive label. To mount the drives with drive letter, we have to add each
entry in `/etc/fstab` (*file system table*). To edit the file, open `/etc/fstab`
file in any text editor in Cygwin, for example nano, vi, vim etc. Comment out
existing lines. For example, assume `C:` drive is labeled with *Windows* and
`D:` drive with *Data*. So, the entries will be `C:` drive to `/mnt/Windows`
and `D:` to `/mnt/Data`. Create those folder with `mkdir`. Now,

before the `/etc/fstab` file was:

```
# This is default anyway:
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0
```

after editing that file:

```
# This is a comment
# This is default anyway:
# none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0

# device-spec  mount-point    fs-type  options              dump  pass
C:             /mnt/Windows   ntfs     binary,posix=0,user  0     0
D:             /mnt/Data      ntfs     binary,posix=0,user  0     0
```

Try not to use any Windows program (e.g. Notepad) to modify that file because
it may change the file permissions. Make sure `/etc/fstab` has `0644` permission.

### Further readings

- [Wikipedia: fstab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab)
- [Cygwin mount](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mount.html)

Comment: I don't have a cygwin installation. I only have rsync.exe, cygwin1.dll, cygiconv-2.dll.

Comment: Then Windows program may be used. If those are in `bin` folder then create `etc` folder and `fstab` file manually. Rest of it may be same.

Comment: But I want to mount every new drive by label which is inserted. Not only some known drives.